# How to run .bin files in 16.04 LTS?

Tags: 16.04, gimp, binary

I downloaded GIMPshop from this [link](http://nchc.dl.sourceforge.net/project/gimpshop.mirror/gimpshop-2.2.11.tar.bz2) and what comes after I unpack the tar.gz is folders and many .bin files

Here is my output of `ls`

```
acinclude.m4.bin       etc                      m4macros
aclocal.m4.bin         gimpdefs.msc.bin         Makefile.am.bin
app                    gimp.pc.in.bin           Makefile.in.bin
AUTHORS.bin            gimpthumb.pc.in.bin      makefile.msc.bin
authors.dtd.bin        gimptool-2.0.in.bin      menus
authors.xml.bin        gimptool-win32.c.in.bin  missing.bin
authors.xsl.bin        gimpui.pc.in.bin         mkinstalldirs.bin
ChangeLog.bin          gimp-zip.in.bin          modules
ChangeLog.pre-1-0.bin  gtk-doc.make.bin         NEWS.bin
ChangeLog.pre-1-2.bin  HACKING.bin              NEWS.pre-2-0.bin
ChangeLog.pre-2-0.bin  INSTALL.bin              NEWS.pre-2-2.bin
compile.bin            install-sh.bin           plug-ins
config.guess.bin       intltool-extract.in.bin  po
config.h.in.bin        intltool-merge.in.bin    po-libgimp
config.h.win32.bin     intltool-update.in.bin   po-plug-ins
config.sub.bin         libgimp                  po-script-fu
configure.bin          libgimpbase              py-compile.bin
configure.in.bin       libgimpcolor             README.bin
COPYING.bin            libgimpmath              README.i18n.bin
cursors                libgimpmodule            README.win32.bin
data                   libgimpthumb             regexrepl
depcomp.bin            libgimpwidgets           themes
devel-docs             LICENSE.bin              tips
docs                   ltmain.sh.bin            tools
```

From what I understand with these files is that, the generic `./configure`, `make`, and `make install` is enough to install them, but the problem is the .bin files and I don't know how to open them.

Comment: You can read README files.

Comment: Is there any reason you want GIMPShop? GIMP is the more modern replacement.

Comment: I'm writing an answer with instructions, if you really want to install GIMPShop and not GIMP.

Comment: @Zacharee1 I will gladly wait sir. Also, I'm very confused with GIMP and I think I can GIMPshop a try.

Comment: I have read the README and INSTALL from that tarball and I think something is wrong, the instructions say run `./configure` (standard instructions) but of course there is no `configure`only `configure.bin`. I don't think all these files should have binary headers. The project seems to have been abandoned too

Comment: Yes I saw it in their website, but still I thought I can at least see what it can do, if no choices then I will be using GIMP.

Comment: @franciskyleflores I've posted my answer.

Comment: Related: [How to install GimpShop on Ubuntu 16.04](//askubuntu.com/a/821985) (answer: DO NOT ATTEMPT TO INSTALL GIMPSHOP)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT:** I did some more digging and it seems like the gimpshop.com website is a fake. It looks like someone else bought the domain after it expired and put up the site that's currently there.

[This](http://freecode.com/projects/gimpshop/) is the real project site, as far as I can tell. Unfortunately, all the links are dead. This [file watcher site](http://www.filewatcher.com/d/FreeBSD/distfiles/Other/gimpshop-2.2.11.tar.bz2.13321989.html) has a few links, but they're all for FreeBSD. It seems as though the `tar.bz2` file isn't necessarily for Mac, but for BSD.

After searching for `GIMPshop-source-2.2.4.tbz`, nothing much has come up.

There seems to be some good news, however. **[Softpedia is providing a download for the GIMPShop 2.2.11 DEB!](http://linux.softpedia.com/get/Multimedia/Graphics/gimpShop-16259.shtml#download)**

Download it from there and install it. Then run `/usr/local/bin/gimp` to run it.

**Another Update:** Thanks to @Zanna's sacrifice (she killed her GIMP install trying GShop out), I can report that it's probably not worth installing GIMPShop. According to her, the application is very broken: stuff just doesn't work. Since it also kills GIMP if it's installed (easy fix, but annoying), I recommend just getting used to using GIMP instead of trying to resurrect something from 2006.

Comment: Sadly, this one also didn't work but still thank you for the answer! This can be useful for things about .bin files.

Comment: @franciskyleflores what exactly went wrong? If this doesn't end up working, nothing will, but there's a possibility you can get it installed.

Comment: bash: ./configure.bin: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error

Comment: @franciskyleflores doing some more research. It's looking like the bz2 file is for Mac. I'll update my answer if I find a way. If not, I'll edit it and explain the problem.

Comment: @franciskyleflores check the answer. I've found a DEB!

Comment: Really? I would like to see that then!

Comment: @franciskyleflores The link is in bold. Second to last paragraph.

Comment: Thank you for the efforts, besides while I'm trying to run it I still have unmet dependencies so, really I thank everyone for giving and discussion their answers here.

Comment: Dependencies can be fixed with `sudo apt-get install -f`, but it's not worth it.

Answer (score 1):

I looked at your link.  It's instructions for installing and older version of Gimp.  It doesn't appear to be instructions for installing on Ubuntu.

You can install a later version of GIMP on Ubuntu from the repository with:

```
$ sudo apt-get install gimp
```

You can also look at the various plugins available for gimp as well as installing it from the Software Center by typing Software Center in the Ubuntu Launch button.  Then use `gimp` for the package search.

Others have already described how to run files.  You can run a bin file from the commandline with:

```
$ ./file.bin
```

Using `file.bin` as the name of the bin file that you are trying to run.  When you download a file it might not have the execution bit set.  You can set it with this command:

```
$ chmod +x file.bin
```

**For your information:**

Gimpshop is a modified version of Gimp to make it look similar to Photoshop. It's old and outdated. You would get better millage with Gimp, whereas Gimp has lots of [support](http://www.gimp.org/), and using its interface might make it easier for you to get answers to any questions or problems you have, as well of using the features.

If you succeed in getting the outdated (and broken) Gimpshop installed, the application will most likely be broken.  You'd also have a hard time getting support trying to use the broken environment.  After extensive research, I couldn't find any official support resource for Gimpshop.

Comment: no worries :) I think OP is better off learning GIMP, this project seems broken

Answer (score 1):

I suggest running GIMP standard like the others, but update its menus to run as Photoshop like as possible: http://lifehacker.com/how-to-make-the-gimp-work-more-like-photoshop-1551318983

The details are in that link, but essentially:

- You can install a small utility to enable a lot of the photoshop shortcuts:  ps-menurc
- Mimic the move tool as per photoshop
- Adjust boundary lines like photoshop
- Snap to canvas like photoshop
- You can add a Layer tool to make the layers work more similarly also (Layer copy cut plugin)

Also you can install a theme pack now that makes it more like Photoshop! http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/08/make-gimp-look-like-photoshop-easy

The pack includes:

- Photoshop icons for the toolbox
- Photoshop keyboard shortcuts (e.g., ‘p’ for pen, ‘c’ for crop, etc.)
- A dark grey background
- Photoshop layout
- Tool options placed on the right-hand side

For this option I would first backup your config folder /.gimp2.x e.g. :

```
mv ~/.gimp-2.8 ~/.gimp-2.8-original
```

Then try the theme.

There are other themes out there too if you are missing certain photoshop things.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following commands:

`sudo chmod +x [filename].bin`

`./[filename].bin`

If the program requires elevated permissions, you can use:

`sudo bash -c './[filename].bin`

Based on the file structure you posted above, you probably want to use `INSTALL.bin`, but I don't know that for sure.

Comment: the INSTALL.bin file is mostly text intended for humans to read, it's not code

Comment: I tried what you just said and here is the result.
cannot execute binary file: Exec format error

Comment: @franciskyleflores please run `file INSTALL.bin`

Comment: @zwork This is very surprising! 'INSTALL.bin: MacBinary III data with surprising version number'

Answer (score 0):

First, open the Terminal, then mark the file as executable with the chmod command.

> chmod +x file-name.bin

Now you can execute the file in the terminal.

```
./file-name.bin
```

If an error message including a problem such as 'permission denied' appears, use sudo to run it as root (admin). Be careful, sudo allows you to make critical changes to your system. Many software installs will require sudo.

```
sudo ./file-name.bin
```

http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-execute-a-run-or-bin-file-in-ubuntu

Comment: Where do you see a `.run` file?

Comment: Please don't copy answers from other websites... besides there is no .run files in my folder.

Comment: Edited : The same thing on Linux ("On a UNIX system, everything is a file; if something is not a file, it is a process.")